# Description language in google search with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, google-search, ngx-translate, angular15

I have developed a web application in angular15 and I have used ngx-translate to make it multilingual. The problem is that when I search for it on google the description is in English regardless of the language of the browser or the search engine. I would like to know if it is possible that the description changes according to the language of the browser. Or failing that it appears in Spanish.
I also have the meta tag "description" but the search engine is not showing it, instead it shows my first <h1> and <p>.

Thank you in advance.

My relevant index.html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tienda</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Descripcion de la tienda en español">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And my component that handles language:

```
export class MyComponent {

  defaultLanguage:string = 'es';
  additionalLanguages:string[] = ['en', 'fr', 'pt'];
  languages: string[] = [this.defaultLanguage].concat(this.additionalLanguages);

  constructor(
    private _translate:TranslateService
  ){
    this.defaultLanguage = this.getDefaultLanguage();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setDefaultLanguage();
  }

  getDefaultLanguage():string{
    let def = 'es';
    if(this.languages.includes(navigator.language)) def = navigator.language;
    else if(this.languages.includes(navigator.language.substring(0,2))) def = navigator.language.substring(0,2);

    return def
  }

  setDefaultLanguage():void {
    this._translate.setDefaultLang(this.defaultLanguage);
    this._translate.addLangs(this.additionalLanguages);
    this._translate.use(this.defaultLanguage);
  }

  setCustomLanguage(languageCode:string):void {
    this._translate.use(languageCode);
    this.setLanguageCookie(languageCode);
  }

}
```